# How do we 'know' that $2^x$ is continuous?

Tags: continuity, exponential-function

It is intuitive for $2^n$, if $n$ is an integer, to exist.

How do we know that less intuitive values such as $2^\frac{1}{2}$, $2^\sqrt{2}$, $2^\pi$ etc exist?

I'd like to accept that $2^x$ is continuous, but how can we be sure of the existence of the number when $x$ is something obscure, like an irrational number?

Comment: Because every value is smooth. There isn't a positive real that will make it jump suddenly.

Comment: Your question and your question's title don't match: you don't want to know about continuity of $\;2^x\;$ but rather about how is that defined when $\;x\;$ is not "a nice" real number.

Comment: The title is matching my question.

My question is regarding the continuity of $2^x$. But to be sure of the continuity, we must be sure that the curve doesn't have any 'holes' in it, hence why I am questioning the existence of a function value when $x$ is 'not nice'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually dealt with by defining $$2^x = e^{x \ln 2}$$ Such a definition works provided we ultimately have a way to define $e^x$ so we can be sure it's continuous.

One way this is done is by defining the exponential function as the the inverse of natural logarithm, which is defined as the definite integral $$\ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$$ This integral is known to exist and be continuous by theorems about integrals of continuous functions on closed intervals. As $\ln$ is also strictly monotonically increasing, the inverse exists and is also continuous

Comment: That's a way of making it rigorous, but I'm not sure rigor is the proper goal here.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132703/what-does-2x-really-mean-when-x-is-not-an-integer/133238#133238) answer. It's pretty good. We just can define these numbers in "most intuitive" way.