# Is $\ln(-1)$ equal to $\pi i$, undefined, or both?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Calculating $\ln(-1)$ with ...

- My calculator: Error (maybe "undefined")
- Advanced calculator: $\pi i$

Comment: The complex ln is not uniquely defined unless we fix the branch we use. If the calculator is not powerful enough to handle complex numbers , it is reasonable that it allows only positive real numbers $x$ in $\ln(x)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547635/do-equal-bases-always-means-equal-exponents/

Comment: Does the calculator support complex numbers?

Answer (score 3):

**answer**

It's a bit more complex:

Actually, all complex solutions are $\ln\left( -1 \right) = \pi \cdot \mathrm{i} + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i} =  \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right)\cdot \mathrm{i}$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ aka there are infinitely many complex solutions in complex.

"Advanced calculators" like Wolfram|Alpha know this sometimes and show this general solution.

**reason**

This is because of zheRelationship between exponential functions and trigonometric functions $\exp\left( x \cdot \mathrm{i} \right) = \cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot \mathrm{i}$ (see Euler's formula) and the periodicity of the $\operatorname{cis}\left( x \right)$ function or of the $\sin\left( x \right)$ function and $\cos\left( x \right)$ function to $2 \cdot \pi$:

$$
\begin{align*}
\ln\left( -1 \right) &= x \cdot \mathrm{i}\\
 x  \cdot \mathrm{i} &= \ln\left( -1 \right) \quad\mid\quad \exp\left( ~~ \right)\\
\exp\left( x \cdot \mathrm{i} \right) &= \exp\left(\ln\left( -1 \right)\right)\\
\operatorname{cis}\left( x \right) &= -1\\
\cos\left( x \right) + \sin\left( x \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} &= -1 \quad\mid\quad \text{Since } -1 \text{ is not imaginary, the } \sin(x) = 0 \text{.}\\
\cos\left( x \right) + 0 \cdot \mathrm{i} &= -1\\
\cos\left( x \right) + 0 &= -1\\
\cos\left( x \right) &= -1 \quad\mid\quad \arccos\left( ~~ \right)\\
\arccos\left(\cos\left( x \right)\right) &= \arccos\left( -1 \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
x &= \arccos\left( -1 \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
x &= \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
\\
\Rightarrow \ln\left( -1 \right) &= \left( \pi + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \mathrm{i} = \pi \cdot \mathrm{i} + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i}\\
\end{align*}
$$

You can write the genral $\ln\left( z \right)$ as

$\ln\left( z \right) = \ln\left( |z| \cdot e^{\left( \arg(z) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right) = \ln\left( |z| \right) + \ln\left( e^{\left( \arg(z) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \mathrm{i}} \right) = \ln\left( |z| \right) + \left( \arg(z) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \mathrm{i}$.

**but it's a bit more complex**

Since the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ are not the only hypercomplex numbers $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ that can have an imaginary unit $\mathrm{i}$ with $\mathrm{i}^{2} = -1$, but also an infinite number of other hypercomplex numbers, e.g. the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ (imaginary units $\mathrm{i}$, $\mathrm{j}$ and $\mathrm{k}$ with $\mathrm{i}^{2} = \mathrm{j}^{2} = \mathrm{k}^{2} = \mathrm{i} \cdot \mathrm{j} \cdot \mathrm{k} = -1$), the octonions $\mathbb{O}$, sedenions $\mathbb{S}$, ..., and you can apply Euler's formula to any hypercomplex number with an imaginary unit $\mathrm{i}_{k}$ with $\mathrm{i}_{k}^{2} = -1$, which means that there are again an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Okernions? Did you mean octonions?

Comment: @HackR Oh yes... A little misstypo. I'll correkt that.

Comment: I voted your answer, although I don't know anything about okernions and etc. But, how do you get $ijk=-1$? Because, $$i^2=j^2=k^2=-1\implies i^2j^2k^2=-1(-1)(-1)=-1≠(-1)^2=1$$ Maybe, I guess this is another algebra?

Comment: @lonestudent This is Hamilton's definition of the imaginary units of the quaternions.
The quaternions are special. Namely, they are not commutative with respect to multiplication aka $\mathrm{k}=\mathrm{i}\cdot\mathrm{j}\ne\mathrm{j}\cdot\mathrm{i}=-\mathrm{k}$. This means that you can't use the square like this: $$(a\cdot b)^{2}=a\cdot b\cdot a\cdot b\ne a\cdot a\cdot b\cdot b=a^{2}\cdot b^{2}$$ You can imagine this units as matrices. Matrices are not commutative with respect to multiplication and you can represend all this units as matrices aka this does not apply to matrices either.

Comment: @KevinDietrich Thank you for clarifications. I see my assumption was true. This is advanved and different topic.